# In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function - Android 4.4, next.js 8.1.0

Tags: javascript, babeljs

When I run my project in Android v4.4.2, I get this error and my project doesn't work.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function`

I added polyfills and @babel/preset-env. but this error is not disappearing.

### Environment

- react: "^16.8.6",
- next.js: "^8.1.0",
- babel: "^7.4.3"

### next.config.js

```
// ...

        const originalEntry = config.entry;
        config.plugins = config.plugins || [];

        // babel-poylfiil
        config.entry = async () => {
          const entries = await originalEntry();

          if (entries['main.js'] && !entries['main.js'].includes('./polyfills.js')) {
            entries['main.js'].unshift('./polyfills.js');
          }

          return entries;
        };

// ...
```

### babel.config.js

```
// ...

presets: ['next/babel', '@zeit/next-typescript/babel', ["@babel/preset-env", {
        targets: {
          ie: 11,
          ios: 9,
          android: 4
        },
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
      }], '@babel/preset-typescript'],

//...
```

What should I do to get rid of that error?

Comment: If you wrote a `function` inside of an `if` somewhere, just refactor that? Thats the easiest and most clean solution

Comment: What is the original code that is transpiled like that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of error.

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7496

I will try to test the next.8.1.1-canary.51 version.